# como leer cada una de las hojas del un excel y guardarlos cada uno en una lista utilizando un ciclo?

Tags: r

son 4 hojas de Excel, el proceso es leer todas todas las hojas y guardarlas como listas mediante  cualquier tipo de ciclo.

`````
for (i in 1:4){
  datos[i] <- list(datos[i])
}````
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes importar datos de un documento de MS Excel con la libería `readxl`

```r
library(readxl)
lista <- rep(list(NA), 4)
for(i in 1:4){
  lista[[i]] <- read_excel(path = "nombre_del_archivo_excel.xlsx", sheet = i)
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda, corrio a la perfeccion